# Twitter bootstrap pagination

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a twitter bootstrap pagination that looks in my html like this

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
       <li class="disabled">
                 <a href="#">«</a>
               </li>
               <li class="active">
               <a href="#">1</a>
               </li>
               <li><a href="http://thevoltagecommunity.loc/music?page=2">2</a>
               </li>
               <li>
               <a href="http://thevoltagecommunity.loc/music?page=2">»</a>
               </li>           
            </ul>
       </div>
```

Now i want to give my last list item a class i need this because i'm using a scroll plugin that needs the element that references to the next page but because the element isn't assigned with a class i can't use it anybody an idea?

Comment: <li class="anyclass"> ?

Comment: no my pagination is generated by laravel framework like this {{ $musicposts->links() }}

Comment: added laravel to your tags. but you can't see the html you just created? it's just an example?

Comment: yes i can see the html but i have no idea how to give the last list item a class

Comment: if you see the html like above you just can add the class like i did in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in JS way:

```
$(function() {
    $('.pagination li:last-child').addClass('someClass');
});
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/wZNN5/